# Redirection in a script

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I'm following a short shell scripting video course, and one of the examples given is:

```
if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
    echo "Need line length argument" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The course material says 'this is printing the errors to standard error.' That doesn't gel with my limited understanding though, I thought the default file descriptor (if unspecified) is '1' (so, in this case stdout, i.e. the above is the same as `1>&2`). In my mind, that would be redirecting/merging stdout to stderr.

Am I missing something about how '&' works as part of a redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just a misunderstanding. "this is printing the errors to standard error" means "standard error is where the output ends up". And you are right that this is "redirecting/merging stdout to stderr". But that is not a contradiction.

The command does not notice this change. The command prints to `stdout` (i.e. fd 1). But before the command is run, the shell makes `stdout` a copy of `stderr`.

```
$ strace -f bash -c '/bin/echo foo >&2'
[...]
dup2(1, 2)                  = 2
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)           = 0
execve("/bin/echo", ["/bin/echo", "foo"], 0x55ffb063e5d0 /* 103 vars */) = 0
[...]
```

`man 2 dup`

> `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);`
> The dup() system call creates a copy of the file descriptor oldfd, using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor for the new descriptor.
> After a successful return, the old and new file descriptors may be used interchangeably.  They refer to the same open file description (see open(2)) and thus share file offset and file status flags; for example, if the file offset is modified by using lseek(2) on one of the file descriptors, the offset is also changed for the other.
> The two file descriptors do not share file descriptor flags (the close-on-exec flag).  The close-on-exec flag (FD_CLOEXEC; see fcntl(2)) for the duplicate descriptor is off.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@HaukeLaging's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/603253/3645), you're right that `>&2` is syntactic sugar for `1>&2`. The `&` should be read as a pointer or indirect reference. Basically `1>&2` in a command means "for this command (or group of commands if using `{}` or `()`) point file descriptor 1 to where file descriptor 2 was pointing before processing this word". But this is *shell* syntax, and is not an argument to the command.